# printing the smallest object in an ArrayList

Tags: java

```
public static double getSmallest(ArrayList<Wert> arr) {
    double small = wert.getZahl();

    for (Wert wert : arr) {
        if (arr.size() < 2) {
            small = wert.getZahl();
        } else {
            if (small > wert.getZahl())
                small = wert.getZahl();
        }
    }

    return small;
}
```

I'm storing objects that contain a value and a unit in an Arraylist. This part should return the smallest value in the array but it always returns `0`.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: Streams afford a much simpler solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this, will return `0` if arraylist is `null` or size with `0` and let's take a look at your mistakes

1) remove that `if` statement in for loop, you should check before looping
 the arraylist

2) let's assume `double small = wert.getZahl();` this the default value top return

3) if arraylist is null or empty return default value

4) or then iterate arraylist, if any of element is smaller than default values assign that to `small` and finally return it

```
public static double getSmallest(ArrayList<Wert> arr) {
    double small = wert.getZahl();

     if(arr==null || arr.isEmpty()){
        return small;
      }
        else {
          for(Wert w : arr) {
            if(small>w.getZahl()) {
                small=w.getZahl();
            }
        }
        return small;
    }
```

By using java-8 most advanced

```
double small = arr.stream().mapToDouble(i->Double.valueOf(getZahl())).min().orElse(wert.getZahl());
```

Comment: I think you should try to help the OP understand the problems with his code rather than giving him the answer.

Comment: `wert` is not defined on line 2.

Comment: you mean it is `Wert`, i did not get you @kamoroso94

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java8 stream function to get complete stats of list.

```
List<Double> arr = Arrays.asList(2.0, 11.0, 13.0, 17.0, 1.5, 19.0, 23.1, 29.1);
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = arr.stream().mapToDouble((x) -> x).summaryStatistics();
System.out.println(stats);
```

Output

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics{count=11, sum=131.600000, min=1.500000, average=11.963636, max=29.100000}
```

You can get only min as well like:

```
System.out.println(stats.getMin());
```

And Output will be:

```
1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for the size of the `ArrayList` or whatever, the only thing you need is `iterate` and `check` :

```
public static double getSmallest(ArrayList<Wert> arr) {
    double small = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Wert wert : arr) {
        if (small > wert.getZahl())
            small = wert.getZahl(); 
    }
    return small;
}
```

or

```
public static double getSmallest(ArrayList<Wert> arr) {
    double small = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Wert wert : arr) {
        small = Math.min(small, wert.getZahl()); 
    }
    return small;
}
```

---

Level-up solution, using `Streams` :

```
public static double getSmallest(ArrayList<Wert> arr) {  
  return arr.stream().map(Wert::getZahl).min(Integer::compareTo).orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: I think you should try to help the OP understand the problems with his code rather than giving him the answer.